# kendo grid mvc client template with multiple params

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Here is the grid:

```
this.Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Filterable()
      .ColumnMenu()
      .Sortable()
      .Groupable()
      .Columns(col =>
      {
          col.Bound(x => x.CompanyId).Visible(false);
          col.Template(x => x.CompanyName).ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("#= CompanyName #>", "Update", "AppCompany", new { id = "#= CompanyId #", panel = 1 }, null).ToHtmlString()).Width(120);
      })
      .Pageable(pageable => pageable
          .ButtonCount(5)
          .Info(true))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(25)
          .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "EmployeeHistory").Data("sendAntiForgery")))
```

I am trying to use both CompanyName and CompanyId to render the ActionLink.

**col.Template(x => x.CompanyName).ClientTemplate(Html.ActionLink("#= CompanyName #>", "Update", "AppCompany", new { id = "#= CompanyId #", panel = 1 }, null).ToHtmlString()).Width(120);**

When the grid renders, I get this error in javascript:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: companyid is not defined**

CompanyId is in a nav property a couple of domain model levels down, but I have mapping set up with Deflattening so Kendo knows where to find it for sorting/grouping, etc.

The question is, how can I get this to work?

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

2 things to note on this.  I had updated Kendo recently, but had not updated the css and js files.  I only updated the dlls in the solution.

Second, the VM property was referencing some DM nav properties that were potentially null.  I think this caused the Kendo grid to not be able to hook in my CompanyId as I wanted.

I now have it working with both CompanyName and CompanyId